# Objective-C method syntax

Tags: objective-c, syntax, methods, arguments

I was surprised when the following method definition compiled (using Apple LLVM 4.1):

```
- (void) testMethod:someArgument {

}
```

Notice the type of `someArgument` is missing. **What's the rule in Objective-C about specifying the types of method arguments?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default argument type is `id`. Even this will compile:

```
- testMethod:someArgument {
}
```

This is a method that takes an `id` as its argument and should return an `id`.

Actually, not even the method name is necessary:

```
- :someArgument {
}
```

This can be called as:

```
[self :someObject];
```

Of course all of this is very bad practice and **you should always specify the types (and the names).**

Comment: Interesting! I like Objective-C even more knowing `-:v{}` compiles :-)

Comment: I refuse to answer any questions that use methods like that :-D

Comment: And if you're looking for the shortest method that compiles, it's probably `-a{}` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The "type" in the method argument is used for type checking by both the compiler and for run-time message passing.

The way it's being called in your prototype up there, it's the equivalent of an "`(id)`".

You can find more information in the "Methods can take Parameters" section of Apple's [Programming with Objective C document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html).  I also see some very helpfun information in the "Object Messaging" section of ["The Objective-C Programming Language" document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW5).

Answer (score 2):

Language specification states:

> If a return or parameter type isn’t explicitly declared, it’s assumed
>   to be the default type for methods and messages—an id.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html

Answer (score 1):

*The Objective-C Programming Language* [tells us](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW3):

> For the object-oriented constructs of Objective-C, such as method
>   return values, id replaces int as the default data type. (For strictly
>   C constructs, such as function return values, int remains the default
>   type.)